# Any substitutes for pexpect?

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I am writing a script using python pexpect to execute another script on a remote machine. It works fine in normal cases, but if there is a `time.sleep` in the remote script, it fails.

I want to get to the remote machine, start the script in the background and get out. Is this possible ?

Can someone suggest an alternative or let me know how to get around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting a timeout on the pexpect command?

Comment: Nope, I will try it out, just a min !

Comment: The connection is established in time, is it possible to add a timeout for pexpect.sendline ???

Comment: Looking at the source code, I don't think so

Comment: aah I c .... That is where the issue is .... I tried ssh with nohup and it works. But still , I have to supply password to the ssh.

Comment: It works if i setup passwordless ssh and then try to use ssh with nohup (Without using pexpect) [Another issue is, This script is not running in background using the ssh nohup] , but I cannot rely on passwordless ssh , I want my code to be a little more generic !!

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might consider daemonize instead of nohup: http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)?

Here's an example ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()

ssh.connect(hostname='example.com', port=22, username='sethu', password='****')

ssh.exec_command('nohup sleep 300 &')

ssh.close()
```